# Simple exercise regarding space spanned by two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vectors $X_1=(1,3,2)$ and $X_2=(-2,4,3)$ in $\mathbb R^3$. Show that the set spanned by $X_1$ and $X_2$ is given by $\{(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3):Y_1-7Y_2+10Y_3=0\}$.

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far? This seems like a standard homework exercise.

Comment: I think the question is wrong because- $\alpha-2\beta=1$, $3\alpha+4\beta=-7$ and $2\alpha+3\beta=10$. These system of equations does not have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The vector product of the two vectors given is

$$\vec n=X_1\times X_2=(1,-7,10).$$

All vectors in the spanned plane will be perpendicular to $\vec n$. So, the equation is 
$$\vec v\cdot \vec n =0.$$

Or, if $\vec v=(x,y,z)$ then the equation is

$$x-7y+10z=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The spannig set is a plane passing through the points  (*1,3,2*) and  (*-2,4,3*).